# ASP.NET MVC + EntityFramework: How to disable this logs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I generate simple asp.net MVC app.
Final file system:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnw8d.png)

Added nugets:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj0aq.png)
Added models:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TESTENTITYLOGGER
{
    public class ATContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } = null!;
        public ATContext(DbContextOptions<ATContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();   // создаем базу данных при первом обращении
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace TESTENTITYLOGGER
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Added HomeController:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace TESTENTITYLOGGER.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ATContext db;
        public HomeController(ATContext _db)
        {
            db = _db;
        }

        public string Index()
        {
            User user = db.Users.First();
            return user.Email;
        }

    }
}
```

Programm.cs:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TESTENTITYLOGGER;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
string connection = @"Server=localhost;Database=Awakened_talents;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=true";

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ATContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
var app = builder.Build();
...
```

EntityFramework logs every interaction with the database:
[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPDGD.png)

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

I tried to change appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I tried to google :(

Comment: Can you show some logs?

Comment: Sorry https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPDGD.png

Comment: You were on the right track - just change `"Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"` to `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Warning"` in your `appsettings.json`. Note that you might need to do it in `appsettings.Development.json` as well so that this logging is disabled on debug.

Comment: Thank you very much. These logs really annoy me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ASP.NET MVC + EntityFramework: How to disable this logs?

Well, if you would like to stop generating autometic log on console tab while your application is running as following:

[image]

**Implementation:**

You can do that. Asp.net core has the [LogginBuilderextension class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#bilp) which provides [`ClearProviders()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#logging-providers) method to stop autometic logging. You can do as following on your `program.cs` file:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
```

**Output:**

Before  ClearProviders:

[image]

AfterClearProviders:

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on logging you could [check our official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)